# How can I tell ack to search in two distinct directories?

Tags: grep, ack

Is it possible to ask `ack` to search and include results from multiple root directories, rather than searching from the current shell working directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can specify any number of files or directories you want to search.

Look at the first line of `ack --help`.

```
Usage: ack [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILES OR DIRECTORIES]
```

(The ack manpage has a similar usage statement)

So you can do

```
ack needle this_haystack/ that/haystack/ other/haystack*.txt
```